# Defragment Everything at Boot Time

Tags: boot, defragment

Is there any defrag tool which defrags every fragmented file at boot time? So far, all of the tools I have seen only defragment the page file, MFT and system files at boot time.

Comment: That's because otherwise booting the system would take far too long.

Comment: Whenever I defragment my HDD, there is always a significant amount fragmentation leftover. I think this is because files are in use during the defragmentation process.

Comment: @Marv wouldn't that make boot times really slow?

Comment: @Marv Possible. If you want to do a full defragmentation, you have to stop all non-vital services before running defrag. Defragmentation is somewhat overrated nowadays, though. As long as you have sufficient free disk-space and fragmentation remains below 15-20% your system should be fine. The only thing I'd really keep an eye on are registry and pagefile fragmentation.

Comment: @Moab Only if I did it at every boot.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Do you know a good registry defragmenter?

Comment: Windows XP and Windows 7 should automatically do this at boot-time, only on Windows 2000 I have used Sysinternals' [PageDefrag](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897426).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Windows does Not defrag at boot time, no version...Vista and W7 defrag on a schedule while windows is running.

Comment: @Marv any reason it has to be done at boot time?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, actually, XP doesn’t defrag the registry hives; PageDefrag is a great tool for it. Vista and up do indeed defrag them, so PageDefrag is unnecessary (though it *can* be run if so desired).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t know about defragging utilities with a built-in option to run on boot (Keltari offered one suggestion), but I would strongly recommend against automatically defragging on *boot*. When Windows boots, there is a *lot* of disk access as it loads the system, the user profile, the autorun programs, etc. If one of these programs is thrashing the hard-drive to defrag it, the whole system will get bogged down to a horrible degree (unless you are using an SSD in which case you shouldn’t be defragging at all).

A better option is to have an auto-defrag run at a later point after the boot process has finished.

Windows Vista+ added a new startup type to Windows services that allows them to be run automatically, but after Windows has booted. You could create a Windows service that runs the defrag program and set it to *Automatic (Delayed)*.

An even better solution is to use a startup-scheduling program like [Startup Delayer](http://www.r2.com.au/page/products/show/startdelay) (figure 1). With it, you can configure it (and most of your other autorun programs) to automatically run on startup, but in a delayed, staggered manner so that the system doesn’t get bogged down and is responsive immediately. For this, you would want to set it to be the last item (e.g., ~2-3 minute delay) so that it the system has stopped most of its disk access by the time it runs.

Of course you will have to check the help-files of whatever defrag tool you like to see what command-line switches it uses (though usually running the executable with the drive-letter is usually sufficient, e.g., `defrag c:`).

(If you have a lot of fragments after defragging; then boot into safe-mode (in which programs are not autorun), and perform a regular defrag at that time so that files are not locked.)

As Ansgar suggested, you can configure [PageDefrag](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897426.aspx) (figure 2) to defrag the registry hives, page and hibernation files, event logs, etc. during the pre-boot. (It can run in Vista+, but is unnecessary.) You can also use (once every two or three blue moons), [NTREGOPT](http://www.larshederer.homepage.t-online.de/erunt/) (figure 3) to compact the registry hives (works in Vista+).

With this set of tools, you can keep your system in top condition.

---

**Figure 1**: Autorunning Windows’ `defrag` program:

[image]

**Figure 2**: PageDefrag’s options

[image]

**Figure 3**: NTREGOPT compacting a registry hive

[image]

---

If you must perform an actual defrag at boot, boot-time defragging is an actual selling point of [UltimateDefrag](http://www.disktrix.com/UltimateDefrag4_boottime.htm).

Answer (score 1):

[UltraDefrag](http://ultradefrag.sourceforge.net/en/index.html) has [boot time](http://ultradefrag.sourceforge.net/handbook/Boot.html) defragmentation.  I have used it in the past, but not recently.  It is free and open-source.

Comment: - http://superuser.com/questions/991444/defrag-pre-optimize-os-data-partition-when-cloning-from-ssd-to-hdd - Any thoughts?